# Show that a continuous map is closed $\iff \overline{f[A]} = f[\overline{A}]$ for all $A \subset X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that a continuous map is closed $\iff \overline{f[A]} = f[\overline{A}]$ for all $A \subset X$.

”$\implies$” Suppose that $f$ is closed.

”$\subset$” Now by definition $f[\overline{A}] \subset \overline{f[A]}$.

”$\supset$” Also by definition $A \subset \overline{A} \implies f[A] \subset f[\overline{A}]$. Now since $f$ is closed it maps closed sets to closed sets and thus $f[\overline{A}]$ is closed. From here we conclude that $\overline{f[A]} \subset\overline{f[\overline{A}]} = f[\overline{A}]$.

Now I have trouble for the other direction ”$\Longleftarrow$”

if I assume that $\overline{f[A]} = f[\overline{A}] $, then how can I show that $f$ is closed?

If I take $y \in \overline{f[A]} $, then I know that there exists open nbdh $O_y$ such that $O_y \cap f[A] \ne \emptyset$. So there is some $f(x) \in O_y \cap f[A]$ and from continuity there is $x \in f^{-1}[O_y] \cap f^{-1}[f[A]] \implies x\in f^{-1}[O_y] \cap  A$ but I don’t see how this is of any help to get to where I need that is $y \in f[\overline{A}]$...

Other way I tried to approach was that if $y \in \overline{f[A]}$, then $\exists x \in A$ such that $y=f(x)$, but this also doesn’t seem to lead anywhere... What other properties of the closure I could use to show this?

Comment: A closed map takes closed sets to closed sets. Suppose $A$ is closed. What can you say about $f(A)$?

Comment: If $f$ was closed $f[A]$ would also be closed. However I cannot assume the thing I’m trying to prove?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Assume $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$. Suppose $A$ is closed. What can you say about $f(A)$? Further hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940164/proving-that-closure-of-set-is-equal-this-set-iff-set-is-closed

Comment: Then $f[A] = f[\overline{A}]$, but $f[\overline{A}] = \overline{f[A]}$ which would show that $f$ is closed since it maps closed sets to closed sets?

Comment: That's it, no need for a question mark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A$ is closed.  Then $A= \overline{A}$.  From here you can use your property to immediately conclude that $f(A)=f(\overline A)=\overline{f(A)}$.